# Performing calculations on output from 2 queries in mysql

Tags: mysql

First query:

```
select count(sales.ucid) as totalOutcomes
from sales
```

Second query:

```
select count(*) as joinedOutcomes
from sales
join calls
on sales.ucid= calls.call_id;
```

I now want to use the output from the second query and divide that by the output from the first query.
Can someone please help with this? Thanks!

Comment: Is `ucid` the primary key of `sales`?

Comment: @forpas I just edited my question. ucid is not the primary key of sales. the relationship between call_id and ucid is 1 to many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both select return only one value, you can use it like following query

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(*) AS joinedOutcomes
        FROM
            sales
                JOIN
            calls ON sales.ucid = calls.call_id)
/  (SELECT 
            COUNT(sales.ucid) AS totalOutcomes
        FROM
            sales)
```

If you want multiple results.

you must Do something like this

```
SELECT t1.ucid ,joinedOutcomes/ totalOutcomes
FROM 
    (SELECT 
            sales.ucid, COUNT(*) AS joinedOutcomes
        FROM
            sales
                JOIN
            calls ON sales.ucid = calls.call_id
            GROUP BY sales.ucid) t1 JOIN
  (SELECT 
            sales.ucid, COUNT(sales.ucid) AS totalOutcomes
        FROM
            sales
            GROUP BY sales.ucid) t2 ON t1.ucid = t2.ucid
```

You need two select that have a common  column, to join them.

If you don't have a Couln for that, you can use ROW_NUMBER as replacement, but you need then a ORDER

Comment: What if both selects returned multiple values? I actually will be extending my previous subqueries to get per day outputs.

Comment: You need to make the two selects in the from clause with a row_number and join them with the row_number, and then divide both values this implies of course you need some kind of order

Comment: So I'm planning on grouping the outputs from each query by date to get the desired outcome from each query and then dividing the per day outcomes in the same way as mentioned in the original question. Now how would I divide the output from the 2 queries? The number of rows returned from each query is the same.

Comment: you really don't expect any further reply, without upvote or acceptance

Comment: I've upvoted the reply. Should I edit my original question for a clearer picture?

Comment: @HAB Please, accept the answer by clicking on the tick.